# User Profile Sync Issues in Office SharePoint Server 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I was following http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/a3c3017e-05e9-40ad-bbe4-c8dc0a3407a4   . When I checked my portal sites. [tp_IsActive] all users has "1", But Mysites profiles database all users [tp_IsActive] is '0'.

Then why portal site collection are not updating where user status is active? Is profile sync will depends on Mysite profiles database "Active" and "InActive" to update portal site.?

After How many days user status will go to InActive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MOSS 2007 it can be rectified by executing stsadm command follow the blog links below to correct it

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deviations/archive/2009/03/25/where-can-the-new-ignoreisactive-parameter-for-the-stsadm-sync-operation-be-used.aspx
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/nishants/archive/2010/08/23/troubleshooting-user-profile-sync-issues-in-office-sharepoint-server-2007.aspx

For SharePoint 2010 people are facing the problem the stsadm command is not working for them.

Since it looks like from your tags you are using MOSS, your problem can be addressed by following above blogs.